# Flutter Application displays data from the previous order with different order number entered

Tags: json, flutter, dart

So I have this issue in my app where the user can enter an order number and it fetches the order details of that number. the problem is whenever I go back to enter another order number it displays the details of the previous order number.

API code:

```
  var response = await http.get(url);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return QrData.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)[0]);
  } else {
    print('error, \nresponse code : ${response.statusCode}');
    throw Exception('Failed to load data');
  }
}

fetchJSONItems() async {
  var response = await http.get(urlItems);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    //String responseBody = response.body;
    //List<dynamic> data = json.decode(responseBody);
    List<dynamic> items = jsonDecode(response.body);
    List<ItemData> convertedItems = [];
    for (var item in items) {
      convertedItems.add(ItemData.fromJson(item));
    }
    //print(items[1]['original_total']);
    return convertedItems;
  } else {
    print('error, \nresponse code : ${response.statusCode}');
    throw Exception('Failed to load data');
  }
}
```

Future that displays the details fetched from the API:

```
  
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:qrscan/qr_scan_page.dart';
import 'main.dart';
import 'UIPrefrences.dart';
import 'API_Preferences.dart';

//List<QrData> qrDataList = [];

class QRDataJSON extends StatefulWidget {
  final String qrLink;

  QRDataJSON({Key key, @required this.qrLink}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _QRDataJSONState createState() => _QRDataJSONState();
}

class _QRDataJSONState extends State<QRDataJSON> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
        title: Text(
          "QR scanner",
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(15.0),
              ),
              color: Colors.grey[100]),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: fetchJSON(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        'Order Details',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 30.0,
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                        height: 30,
                                      ),
                                      Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                        children: [
                                          CustomerProperty(
                                              propertyName: 'Order date',
                                              value: snapshot.data.orderDate),
                                          CustomerProperty(
                                              propertyName: 'Invoice ID',
                                              value: snapshot.data.invoiceID),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding:
                                            const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                                        child: Container(
                                          width: double.infinity,
                                          height: 0.5,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      CustomerProperty(
                                          propertyName: 'Name',
                                          value: snapshot.data.nameAr),
                                      CustomerProperty(
                                          propertyName: 'email',
                                          value: snapshot.data.email),
                                      CustomerProperty(
                                          propertyName: 'phone',
                                          value: snapshot.data.phone),
                                      CustomerProperty(
                                          propertyName: 'code',
                                          value: snapshot.data.code),
                                      PaymentStatues(
                                        propertyName: 'Payement Statues',
                                        value: snapshot.data.paymentStatues,
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding:
                                            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                                        child: CurrencyProperty(
                                          propertyName: 'Subtotal',
                                          value: snapshot.data.subTotal,
                                          curValue: snapshot.data.currency,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding:
                                            const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                                        child: Container(
                                          width: double.infinity,
                                          height: 0.5,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Items',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                                  //textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                ),
                                FutureBuilder(
                                  future: fetchJSONItems(),
                                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                      return SizedBox(
                                        height: 420,
                                        child: ListView.builder(
                                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                              int index) {
                                            return ItemRow(
                                                nameEng: snapshot
                                                    .data[index].nameEng,
                                                currency: snapshot
                                                    .data[index].currency,
                                                img: snapshot.data[index].img,
                                                orgTotal: snapshot
                                                    .data[index].orgTotal,
                                                quantity: snapshot
                                                    .data[index].quantity);
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                                    } else {
                                      return Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            top: 200, bottom: 289),
                                        child: Center(
                                            child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                                      );
                                    }
                                  },
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                    }
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 200, bottom: 289),
                      child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 350.0,
                  height: 60.0,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        qrText = '';
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (BuildContext context) => AppQR()));
                      });
                    },
                    color: Colors.blue[900],
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    child: const Text(
                      'Confirm Delivery',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                    ),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

QR scan page:

```
var qrText = '';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  //qr setup
  GlobalKey qrKey = GlobalKey();

  QRViewController controller;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: QRView(
                key: qrKey,
                overlay: QrScannerOverlayShape(
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    borderColor: Colors.green,
                    borderLength: 30,
                    borderWidth: 10,
                    cutOutSize: 300),
                onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreate),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  bool isRead = false;
  void _onQRViewCreate(QRViewController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
      setState(() {
        qrText = scanData;
        //print("Hello: $qrText");
        if (isRead == false) {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => QRDataJSON(
                        qrLink: qrText,
                      )));
        }
        isRead = true;
        return 0;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you go back from order screen and move to it again?

Comment: yes but you need to re-enter the order number

Comment: What are you mean as "go back to enter another order number it displays the details of the previous order number"? Go back to screen with order?

Comment: when you launch the app you can scan a QR code or enter order ID . in both situations you will be directed to the details page. however, when you press back button and try to enter another "order number" it displays the previous order information rather than the new one.

Comment: Can you add full code of screen with QR scanner and page with order?

Comment: Okay i have updated the code

Comment: Can you post `fetchJSON()` method?